# One MySQL Database & Multiple Table

Tags: php, mysql, database

How to connect to a certain table in MySQL database?

I have tried :

```
mysql_select_db("baybeestore",$connection);
```

but it gives me an error :-

```
"Error : Table 'baybeestore.form' doesn't exist"
```

But I've created a table named as `order`. Are there any PHP codes to connect to my table `order` in the same database that have multiple databases?

Is it wise enough to create multiple database & one table for one website
or multiple table with one database?

FULL CODE :

```
$connection = mysql_connect("localhost","user","1234");
    if(!$connection)
    {
        die('Failed to connect to MySQL :' . mysql_error());
    }
    mysql_select_db("baybeestore",$connection)
    $sql = "INSERT INTO
    form(name, address, email, handphone, item, payment)

    VALUES
    ('$strname', '$straddress', '$stremail', '$strhandphone', '$stritem', '$strpayment')";

    if(!mysql_query($sql, $connection))
    {
        die('Error : ' . mysql_error());
    }
    echo "Data have been saved.";
    mysql_close($connection);
```

Comment: The usual way is one database per application (or application domain) with multiple tables.

Comment: Don't use mysql_* use either PDO or mysqli. It's deprecated.

Comment: You should have a look at this youtube series http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BEbKji_pSZM . Hope this helps! :)

Comment: You need to post your full code. I'm rather a "bad shot" in the dark ;-) Something else in your code is causing this. And don't **waste your time** with `mysql_` you'll eventually be forced to re-code everything, plus it's not safe to use those functions.

Comment: posted my full code @Fred-ii-

Comment: As per your edit/added code. You're using two different tables for your queries. Result: **ERROR** You have `SELECT * FROM order` and `INSERT INTO form` 2 different animals altogether. If anything, that should be `INSERT INTO order` or `SELECT * FROM form` yet... `ORDER` is a reserved word and should be enclosed with backticks. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html

Comment: @Fred-ii- , problem solved. ive missed that "form" part. checked for so many times but didnt realize til u mention em. Thanks ! :D

Comment: I suggest you [**read this article on `INSERT`**](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-insert-query.htm) along with everything else listed on that website, and/or find tutorials on `mysqli_` and PDO. Stop using `mysql_` functions also. I myself studied Database syntax for 6 months, and spent 3 months testing and building from tutorials before I felt I was good and ready. If you have the time to do so, you will have much better success with your code, believe me ;-)

Comment: Would you like me to put my comment in as an answer, in order to close the question? Otherwise it will remain as unanswered.

Comment: Since my comment did in fact help you to resolve the problem ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- yes sure do put your comment as the answers :)

Comment: [It's posted here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20571707/1415724)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per your edit/added code. [**Your originally posted code**](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/20570810/2)

You're using two different tables for your queries. Result: **ERROR**

You have `SELECT * FROM order` and `INSERT INTO form` 2 different animals altogether.

If anything, that should be `INSERT INTO order` or `SELECT * FROM form` yet... `ORDER` is a [**reserved word**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html) and should be enclosed with backticks.

I.e.:

```
INSERT INTO `order`
```

- **http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html**

Answer (score 4):

This is a very confusing question. `mysql_select_db("baybeestore",$connection);` has nothing to do with table names, so your error must be coming from somewhere else. Also, the error refers to the table `form`, but you say you have created a table named `order`.

To answer your questions:

1. You don't connect to tables; you connect to databases and run queries against tables. Connect to `my_database` or whatever, then run queries like `SELECT * FROM my_table`.
2. One database, multiple tables -- *definitely* not multiple databases, which is much more complicated, generates a ton of overhead, and doesn't help in any way.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are confusing things. You are supposed to connect to a database and then run queries against one or multiple tables in that database.

So if you have database `My_Database` and tables `table1`, `table2` you could run

```
mysqli_select_db($connection, "My_Database");
```

and then run queries like

```
$result = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE 1 LIMIT 1");
```

please note that I have changed the function names to `mysqli_*` because `mysql_*` functions are deprecated and should not be used anymore

Comment: Side note: The `mysqli_` api method, [`mysqli_query()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) requires a database connection as the first argument. Example from the manual `if (mysqli_query($link, "CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE myCity LIKE City") === TRUE) {`.

Answer (score 1):

Now that you are learning, I recommend you to start learning the correct way. Don't use mysql_ functions. Try learning PDO. Also, use one database per application.

To connect you can try:

```
    try {
    $conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=myDatabase', $username, $password);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
```

You can learn more about PDO through [this link](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/php-database-access-are-you-doing-it-correctly/)